# How to make automatic backup [daily , weekly ,...] using Java and mysql database "wamp server"?

Tags: mysql, javafx, java-8, wampserver, database-backups

I'm creating a javafx app with using wamp server for mysql database, how to make automatic backup even if database become large for a specific location, Or  what's best practice in this case?
What can I do by java for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to create a cron job for this.

You can either invoke mysqldump tool directly or create a script in any language to export data you want to, which requires more work,  but is more flexible.

Alternatively you can search the Internet for some ready tool (like [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) which I just found, but didn't check if it works). I'm pretty sure you would find some, since it's pretty common thing to do.

Comment: well, looks to me like he actually helped you. begging for upvotes is not very cool, my friend. engage in community and you'll get your upvotes and will also learn smt useful. also, my 5 cents here would be that windows doesn't have cron per se - but you can still create automatic tasks. also, there's always an option to use linux :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot it's about **W**AMP. Anyway, Windows has a Task Scheduler which would do the job too.